# how put directory in string , in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to know what the current directory is. I don't want to shell out to run pwd. Is there an easy way to do this in Dart?
and also,
Is there a way, put name of directory into a string?

Answer (score 2):

Re the current directory, from the documentation from the [Directory](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-io/Directory-class.html) class in [dart:io](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) (emphasis added).

> In addition to being used as an instance to access the file system,
>   Directory has a number of static properties, such as systemTemp, which
>   gets the system's temporary directory, **and the getter and setter
>   `current`, which you can use to access or change the current directory.**

To get the name of a `Directory` as a string just use `toString()`, or perhaps the `path` property.